# Save fails on raster object created from NumpyArrayToRaster?

Tags: raster, arcpy, geotiff-tiff, numpy, esri-grid-format

I am trying to save an ESRI grid built from a numpy array and am getting an error I've never seen before:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
>   'GpMetadataFunctions, Version=10.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'GpMetadataFunctions, Version=10.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86'    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String
>   assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Boolean forIntrospection)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString)    at GetManagedType(Char* _assembly, Char* _path,
>   Char* _className)
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

I'm using an alternative workflow for now, but I'd still like to try to solve the problem with saving a raster from a numpy array.

Here is what I was trying to do:

1. read in an ESRI grid,
2. create an numpy array,
3. do some manual reclassification, and
4. save the processed array to a new ESRI grid

The process proceeds as expected through step 3 and fails upon step 4 *AFTER* the array has been converted to a raster object (see code below). It is when the `save` method of the raster is called that the error is encountered.

I got the same error when trying to create a numpy array from geo-tiff rasters (failed on calling `arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray`); I was able to get around this by copying the original .tifs to ESRI grid format first.

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = 'SwbLandUseParameters.gdb'

# List tables to use in the reclassification
tables = arcpy.ListTables('SwbLandUseParameters*')

# List land use rasters
lu_rasters = arcpy.ListRasters('nlcd*', 'GRID')

for lu_raster in lu_rasters:

    print 'Processing raster', lu_raster

    # Get raster properties
    r = arcpy.Raster(lu_raster)
    ll = r.extent.lowerLeft
    x_cell_size = r.meanCellWidth
    y_cell_size = r.meanCellHeight
    ncol = r.width
    nrow = r.height
    year = lu_raster[-4:]

    # Convert the raster to a numpy array
    lu = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(r, ll, ncol, nrow)

    # Create a suite of reclassified rasters using parameter tables
    for tbl in tables:
        temp = np.copy(lu)
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl, '*') as cur:
            for row in cur:
                print row
                old_val = row[1]
                new_val = row[2]
                temp[temp==old_val] = new_val
        new_raster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(temp, ll, x_cell_size, y_cell_size, 0)
        new_raster_name = tbl + '_' + year
        print '  ', new_raster_name
        new_raster.save(new_raster_name)
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this using less code and a tiny raster dataset?

Comment: I have not had a chance to test this on a smaller case yet, but will try to do so.

Comment: For me it happen when I supplied the wrong file path in the function input.